# Blown out highlight on sony camera

Tags: sony

[image][image]

Hi

Thanks to people that responded my first question, but now I’m going to elaborate more about my problem.

So, I switched from canon (EOS 600d) to Sony (a7ii) two weeks ago, I gotta say the transition is quite hard since i used canon for like 1 year.

One thing that is quite problematic on sony is that it always washes out the highlight, as you can see on the first picture, the cloud was supposed to be seen but somehow, sony washed it over and it looks bad, meanwhile on canon, and and also my phone, the highlight is not blown out, it is visible, as you can see on the second picture, it’s just fine.

I did check the settings on my camera, and I believe I don’t change that much from default in both camera, i use manual mode, set the white balance on auto, JPEG, and the rest is all just on default, so I don’t really know what is wrong on sony.

If you guys know what the problem is, than your help is needed, if you need to know about certain settings just tell me and I’ll check the setting.

Thank you. And have a great day everyone

Comment: why not simply edit your own orignal question? voting to close this as duplicate.